# What am I missing in libGDX to get InputEvent on Actor?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libGDX on Android. I set up the Stage and added a CustomActor with a custom draw. It's working properly. However, I am not able to get any logs for the touchDragged method via the InputListener for this actor. Even the code within it does not run.

Here is the required exposure to the code:

```
public class CustomActor extends Actor {
    public CustomActor() {
        this.setListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                //This log doesn't print up!
                Gdx.app.log("CustomActor","touchDragged");
                //This code doesn't work either
                Vector2 v = CustomActor.this.localToParentCoordinates(new Vector2(x,y));
                CustomActor.this.setPosition(v.x, v.y);  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out here on what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `Stage` you are using as `InputProcessor` to receive the events else the `Stage` can't forward the event to the actors.

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks BennX, I've done this already in the create() method. Widgets added on the stage gets logs in their attached InputListeners but not the custom extended actor. Widgets are already derived from Actor and I am just surprised. Can you provide any help now ?

Answer (score 0):

1. try using

   ```
   public boolean addListener (EventListener listener) {...}
   ```

   method of Actor. Which version of libgdx are you using?  I think actor does not have "setListener" method.
2. Check your actor bounds. (width & height)

Comment: The Actor has addListener() method. I am using the latest nightly build and the latest nightly documentation. using actor.setSize(300,300) for width and height. Also, as I said in my description, I am able to perform a custom draw over the actor and it is visible on the stage properly. It just doesn't enter into touchDragged method in its attached listener. can you help ?